# Why Can't I Do This Foreach in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my controller action:

```
<EmployeeAuthorize()>
Function HRA_Table() As ActionResult

    ' get current employee's id
    Dim db1 As EmployeeDbContext = New EmployeeDbContext
    Dim user1 = db1.Tbl_Employees.Where(Function(e) e.Employee_EmailAddress = User.Identity.Name).Single()
    Dim empId = user1.Employee_ID
    Dim empSSN = user1.Employee_SSN

    Dim hra = db.Tbl_HRAs.Where(Function(x) x.SSN = empSSN)

    Return View(hra.ToList)

End Function
```

This is my model:

```
Public Class Tbl_HRA

    <Key()> Public Property HRA_ID() As Integer
    Public Property SSN() As String
    Public Property Height() As Double
    Public Property Weight() As Double
    Public Property Nic_EE() As String
    Public Property Nic_SP() As String
    Public Property BMI() As Double
    Public Property BP_S() As Double
    Public Property BP_D() As Double
    Public Property HDL() As Double
    Public Property LDL() As Double
    Public Property Tot_Chol() As Double
    Public Property Continine() As String
    Public Property Glucose() As Double
    Public Property Waist() As Double
    Public Property Hip() As Double
    Public Property Triglycerides() As Double
    Public Property A1C() As Double
    Public Property LDL_HDL() As Double

End Class
```

This is my view:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of GemcoBlog.Tbl_HRA)

@Code
    Layout = Nothing
End Code

@For Each item In Model

    @item.Height

Next
```

The error I get is:

> The 'Height' property on 'Tbl_HRA' could not be set to a 'String'
>   value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type
>   'Double'.

I can't seem to understand why this error is occurring.  I tried changing it to `double` based on some articles I read, but still it won't work!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: It points to `Return View(hra.ToList)` on my controller action, but I only get the error when I try to perform the `For Each` loop in my view.

Comment: It looks like this could be caused by this database...  It looks like they set these to `varchar` instead of `double` which is ridiculous...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, it appears that the column in the table is a varchar. As a result, your model must define it as a string. Try changing the height property to be as follows:

```
 Public Property Height() As String
```

Unfortunately, you can't do type conversions directly in the LINQ to SQL implementation. If you want, you could project into another type (in the Select clause), but you would still need the immediate fetch (context.GetTable(Of T)) to have the types be equivalent between your database and the model.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I know.  Instead of using string; however, I believe I will try to get them to change the database column to use double or decimal.

Answer (score 0):

This article might be of use - looks like an issue with your database schema? Is this column set as nullable in table?

http://digitaltoolfactory.net/blog/2012/03/how-to-fix-yet-another-you-must-set-this-property-to-a-non-null-value-of-type-double-problem-with-entity-framework/

Comment: That is one of the exact articles that I read.  I changed the type to `decimal` but I don't know how to do non null.

Comment: In the db table designer its just an checkbox option. Or in EF designer if you're using that its available as a property of the column. Or in VB.Net I think setting property like this

Public Property Height() As Nullable(Of Double)

might work

Comment: I have already tried that, too.  It also doesn't make the loop work.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you

```
<ul>
    @For Each g As MvcApplication1.Genre In Model
        @<li>@g.Name</li>
    Next
</ul>
```

and also see this url for more help

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic

Comment: This is VB, not C#.  Thanks, anyway.

Comment: No, I am using VB.  So, I need VB.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be caused by this database.  It looks like they set these to varchar instead of double which is not ideal.